# Get tweets that are not mentions

Tags: twitter

Is there a way of getting tweets that are **not mentions** directly from the Twitter API? i.e. Status updates only.
I want this:

> StackOverflow rules

This is ok too:

> it's cold today @randomUser

But not this:

> @randomUser i agree

I've looked at both the REST and Streaming APIs and cannot find a way to filter in this way.

Client side filtering is an option but it's dirty.

Reference:
Twitter API docs: http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: What do you mean by client side filtering being "dirty"? Isn't it just a simple matter of discarding any tweets that start with @?

Comment: Say I want 3 status tweets, but the timeline has 50 at-replies followed by status tweets, then I'll have to keep fetching results until they aren't replies.

Answer (score 3):

The Twitter API now supports excluding replies when fetching timeline. Just set exclude_replies=true in your request.

Source: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Answer (score 0):

No, the API does not have an endpoint or filter that allows for that.

Also, this is considered a mention:

> it's cold today @randomUser

What you're describing, I think, is referred to as a reply, even if it's not in reply to a tweet.

Comment: is this still true 2 years later?

Comment: Yup. A reply does mention a user, so replies are included in the mentions timeline.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you're asking if you can fetch the full sample, then filter out the replies yourself, then yes, you can.

Comment: I guess I was wondering if you created a list in twitter if the behavior is the same when querying a list. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search shows the from:author syntax but I'm not sure. Client side filtering seems like the easy choice and for our scenario of showing n recent tweets on a website without showing ones that start with @ mention will just need some extra logic to make sure we still display n tweets even if the last 5 started with @ mention